# How to configure WPP to instrument code in header files (such as templates)?

Tags: c++, windows, templates, drivers, windows-wpp

My driver project uses several template classes which are implemented in c++ header files.

By default WPP runs only on .c and .cpp source files, and does not process .h files at all.

I have followed the instructions in [How do I generate trace messages from a header file?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546762(v=vs.85).aspx)
 from MSDN, however the .h files are still not being processed by WPP.

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN documentation omits an important additional step - WPP is not called for "h" files, therefore you have to direct it manually by adding

```
\\path\\to\\header\\header.h
```

to the WPP command line.

(or add `\\path\\to\\header\\*.h` to process multiple files)

You can configure visual studio to do this for you like so:

[image]